# How to start AWS SWF workflow with a mail?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I've defined a workflow in SWF implementing the workers in Java code and it's working as expected. However, I'd like to be able to start an instance of it by sending a mail. What are the good practices to do it? Is there any example published? Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't have an example for you, but you can receive incoming emails with AWS SES, SES can then be setup to invoke a Lambda function upon receipt and once running in Lambda you can pretty much do anything you want - including starting an SWF worker.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-receipt-rules.html

> **Creating Receipt Rules for Amazon SES Email Receiving**
>
> A receipt rule enables you to specify what you want Amazon SES to do
>   with mail it receives for one or more recipients or domains. The
>   receipt rule consists of a condition and an ordered list of actions.
>   If the recipient to which the incoming mail is addressed matches a
>   recipient specified in the condition, then Amazon SES performs the
>   actions specified in the receipt rule. For more information about the
>   role of receipt rules in the email-receiving process, see
>   Email-Receiving Concepts.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this option